# Play! 2.2 Subproject Split Routing

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm working on splitting a Scala/Play! 2.2 project into modules. The route splitting is failing to compile, but the actual source code does seem to compile. Here's the code that I think is relevant to the problem:

**/build.sbt**:

```
import play.Project._

name := "edshare_play"

Common.settings

playScalaSettings

libraryDependencies ++= Common.libraryDependencies

routesImport += "_root_.utils.binders._"

resolvers ++= Common.resolvers

scalacOptions ++= Common.scalacOptions

Keys.fork in Test := false

lazy val root = project.in(file("."))
                       .aggregate(core, edmoderator)

lazy val edmoderator = project.in(file("modules/edmoderator"))
                              .dependsOn(core)

lazy val core = project.in(file("modules/core"))
```

**/conf/routes**:

```
# Moderation API
->  /api/edmoderation               edmoderator.Routes

# Core API
->  /api                            core.Routes
```

**/modules/edmoderator/conf/edmoderator.routes**:

```
GET     /:entity               controllers.edmoderator.Moderation.getUnmoderated(entity)
PUT     /:entity/:id           controllers.edmoderator.Moderation.moderateDocument(entity, id)
```

**/modules/core/conf/core.Routes**:

```
GET     /entity/:entity                     controllers.Entity.list(entity)
```

The compiler outputs this:

```
[error] /Users/user/dev/project/play/conf/routes:6: not found: value edmoderator
[error] ->  /api/edmoderation               edmoderator.Routes
[error] /Users/user/dev/project/play/conf/routes:9: not found: value core
[error] ->  /api                            core.Routes
[error] /Users/user/dev/project/play/conf/routes: not found: value edmoderator
[error] /Users/user/dev/project/play/conf/routes:9: not found: value edmoderator
[error] ->  /api                            core.Routes
[error] /Users/user/dev/project/play/conf/routes:6: not found: value handler
[error] ->  /api/edmoderation               edmoderator.Routes
[error] /Users/user/dev/project/play/conf/routes:9: not found: value handler
[error] ->  /api                            core.Routes
[error] 6 errors found
```

I figure that there is probably a simple mistake I'm making somewhere, but I'm unable to find it. Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are missing the following in your config:

```
lazy val root = project.in(file("."))
                        .aggregate(core, edmoderator)
                        .dependsOn(core, edmoderator)
```

instead of just:

```
lazy val root = project.in(file("."))
                       .aggregate(core, edmoderator)
```

You can look at a sample here:

https://github.com/cnicodeme/play2.2-subproject

Comment: Yep, makes perfect sense. Thanks!